# Laravel Database filter total greater than and using distinct

Tags: laravel, database

How can I filter out only one results when total payment is greater than bill?

I tried 3 ways like this but still didn't work

Thank you

1.trial to one (not working)

```
$paid_off= Instalments::distinct()->whereRaw('bills >= payments ')->get();
```

2.second try (not working)

```
$paid_off = DB::table('instalments')
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as badanusaha_id, badanusaha_id')
        ->where(('Sum(bills )'), '>=', ('Sum([payments][1] )'))
        ->groupBy('badanusaha_id')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

3.third try (not working)

```
$pem1 = Instalments::distinct(DB::raw("CAST(SUM(bills) as int) as pem1"));
$pem2 = Instalments::select(DB::raw("CAST(SUM(payments ) as int) as pem2"));
        
        if($pem1 >= $pem2){
            $paid_off = Instalments::distinct()->select('*')->get();
        }
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKiQ1.png)

from this image, only show one data that is PT Mandiri because total payments grather than total bills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve here. but from the last statement you mentioned

> only show one data that is PT Mandiri because total payments grather
> than total bills

this query will work as expected:

```php
$instalments = Instalments::query()
   ->whereRaw('payments >= bills')
   ->groupBy('badanusaha_id')
   ->get();
```

result:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1357 ▼
    +"id": 1
    +"badanusaha_id": 45
    +"bills": "100.00"
    +"payments": "100.00"
  }
]
```

Comment: It's work, thanks a lot sir !!, makasih kang